# Display listview item containing a button in it as a overlay on top of other listview item's on click

Tags: android

Display listview item containing a button in it as a overlay on top of other `listview` item's on click in android

Comment: Do you mean overlay design wise (the button covers part of the text or whatever else is in the listView) or just that the onClick overlays the onClick of the rest?

Comment: ok..so let me frame my question in this way. so can i have a sliding drawer for each ListView 'item'. Let's say i have 20 items in a list and onclick of each item there will be a drawer which will contain a button in it and onclcik of that button will perform some action specific to that item.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question and comment, I think this is what you need to do:

Set the onClick for the items in the ListView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener () {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> _av, View _v, int _index, long arg3) {
        //Sliding drawer code
    }
});
```

In your getView code you will set an OnClickListener to the button

```
Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Code to determine what button does
    }
});
```

Since each button has a different action, you'll probably want a function, switch statement, or something similar to determine what action to set.

Comment: hmm.. it may be the one way to achieve it..but i will be using layout inflater don't know if it works..lets see thanks for the help @CameronW